opendkim and memcached not working together
I'm trying to connect opendkim with memcached, but I'm getting the following error:
root@ad66fb76c1d5:~# /usr/sbin/opendkim -x /etc/opendkim.conf -u opendkim -P /var/run/opendkim.pid
opendkim: opendkim-db.c:6433: dkimf_db_walk: Assertion `0' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)

Here are the relevant lines from my opendkim.conf:
KeyTable memcache:localhost/key
SigningTable memcache:localhost/sign

and here is my command line:
/usr/sbin/opendkim -x /etc/opendkim.conf -u opendkim -P /var/run/opendkim.pid
memcached is indeed running and accessible:
root@ad66fb76c1d5:~# telnet localhost 11211
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
stats
STAT pid 7
STAT uptime 4018
...

I'm using the Ubuntu distribution of opendkim, and it is compiled with memcache support.
I'm out of ideas... anyone?
